# ios ignoring viewWillDisappear

Tags: ios, uiview

I have a form on a tabbed view; I mark the form dirty of any of the fields have been changed and I want to pop up an ActionSheet with "save"/"cancel" if the form is dirty (in lieu of a "save" button). Is there any way to stop the view from disappearing (or being removed from the view stack) until the user responds to the ActionSheet being handled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. It's worth noting that Apple's [Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW23) (the HIG) explicitly discourages this practice. They suggest that apps should "ask people to save only when necessary" because people "should have confidence that their work is always preserved unless they explicitly cancel or delete it." Perhaps in your case, it's important to have this feature, but it's generally discouraged.
2. An alternative, if you want to give users the chance to revert to old settings is to provide an "undo" button, that way, you honor the HIG and effectively auto-save, but you also give the user to explicitly revert to prior values if they really need to.
3. As others have noted, the notion of prompting to save or discard on `viewWillDisappear` doesn't quite work. It's logically too late in the process. `viewWillDisappear` could be called for too many reasons, many of which are not under your control, and it's not copacetic to fail to return promptly to that method, to introduce new user interface elements, etc.
4. If you really, really need the "save" vs. "cancel" user interface, then that lends itself to more of a modal interface (or push a new view controller that you have to pop off to return to your tab bar view controller) with save and cancel buttons rather than a tab bar interface. E.g. your tab bar view could show current values, you tap on an "edit" button, which pushes new view with save and cancel buttons. We don't know enough about your app to be able to advise whether this is logical in your case or not. (For another approach, see [enabling edit mode in view controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/EnablingEditModeinaViewController/EnablingEditModeinaViewController.html).)

Comment: Robert is right. If you've built a tabbed interface any instance of blocking the user from accessing other tabs when they want to is a failure of design and HIG. You need to rethink your process and consider autosaving.

Comment: Yeah... I've refactored a bit... I'm now dynamically creating a "save" button on the uinav bar that will show when a user changes any data on the form... thanks for the insight and suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You can't stop the view from disappearing once the app has progressed to the point where `viewWillDisappear:` has been called. The thing to do would be to create a function like:

```
- (void)saveAndClose {
    //Display sheet asking user what they want to do
}


- (void)dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0) // 0 or whatever the index of your save button is
    {
        // Perform save functions
    }

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; // or pop the view controller if appropriate
}
```

Comment: Just noticed this was happening from a UITabBar action. In that case, I'm afraid you don't have a lot of options there. What I would look at would be taking over the entire screen (possibly utilizing the AppDelegate) to 'dim' the screen and display your alert. If you need help with that, let me know.